# Trouble sending POST parameter with androidannotations

Tags: android, post, android-annotations

so I'm trying to send a simple String to my REST server from an Android app using androidannotations.

```
http://localhost:8080/TestServer_RESTJersey/api/lanceurs/parPays
```

Using Advanced REST client chrome extension, I send the parameter :

```
country=Europe
```

and it's working fine. Now my problem whith the Android app is that my request is received by the server, but the country parameter is always null. My others GET requests are all working perfectly.

Here is my RestClient class :

```
@Rest(converters = {MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.class, FormHttpMessageConverter.class})
    public interface RestClient extends RestClientRootUrl, RestClientSupport{

        @Get("/poke/simple")
        public MessageResponse simplePoke();

        @Get("/api/lanceurs/{name}")
        public LaunchVehicleResponse nameRequest(String name);

        //server doesn't get the parameter here...
        @Post("/api/lanceurs/parPays")
        public LaunchVehicleResponse countryRequest(String country);        
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated as usual, thanks!

EDIT :

server-side REST api :

```
@Path("api/lanceurs/parPays")
    @POST
    public String getLanceurByCountry(@FormParam("country") String country)
    {
        initData();
        LaunchVehicleResponse lvr = new LaunchVehicleResponse();
        ArrayList<LaunchVehicle> allv = myDatabase.getDataByCountry(country);
        lvr.setData(allv);
        return parseObjectToJson(lvr);
    }
```

Comment: by the way, I know that Europe isn't a country, but that's normal =D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it seems I figured out a way to get myself out of this mess.

I made a class LaunchVehicleRequest on my client, containing (among other things) a country String. When I need to send a request to my server, I instantiate this class and initialize LaunchVehicleRequest.country with the value I want (ex: "USA"). Then I send the whole object to my RestClient.

```
LaunchVehicleRequest lvreq = new LaunchVehicleRequest();
lvreq.setCountry("Europe");
LaunchVehicleResponse lvr = pm.countryRequest(lvreq);
```

...

```
    @Rest(converters = {MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.class, FormHttpMessageConverter.class}, interceptors = { LoggingInterceptor.class } )
    public interface RestClient extends RestClientRootUrl, RestClientSupport, RestClientHeaders{
        @Post("/api/lanceurs/parPays")
        public LaunchVehicleResponse countryRequest(LaunchVehicleRequest request);
}
```

I set up the same class on my server-side, which get the request as a string and then convert it in an object.

```
@Path("api/lanceurs/parPays")
@POST
public String getLanceurByCountry(String request)
{
    //  request={"country":"USA"}       
    //my json parsing function here
    LaunchVehicleRequest lvreq = parseJsonToRequest(request);
    ...
}
```

I don't know is this is the best way, but hey it's working fine now and I'm using my LaunchVehicleRequest class for every different request I can need to, so it's not THAT bad I guess ^^'

Thanks everyone anyway ;)

Answer (score 0):

In JAX-RS, use @QueryParam annotation to inject URI query parameter into Java method. example,@QueryParam("country") String countryName,
Try the below, i guess, it should work

```
    @Post("/api/lanceurs/parPays")
    public LaunchVehicleResponse countryRequest(@QueryParam("country") String country);
```

Comment: Are you talking about client-side or server-side ?
If I do so server-side, it doesn't work and even make that my Advanced REST extension requests are broken, just like the Android app.

I'm using androidannotations on the client, and JAX-RS on my server.

Thanks anyway for helping me ;)

Answer (score 0):

As explained on the [wiki](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Rest%20API#post), you can send form parameters this way:

```
@Rest(rootUrl = "http://company.com/ajax/services", converters = { FormHttpMessageConverter.class, MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.class })
public interface MyRestClient extends RestClientHeaders {

    @RequiresHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE)
    @Post("/api/lanceurs/parPays")
    public LaunchVehicleResponse countryRequest(MultiValueMap<String, Object> data);  

}

MultiValueMap<String, Object> data = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
data.set("country, "Europe");

client.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE);


client.countryRequest(data);
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried somethig like that previously, but wasn't successful.
First I have to write this :

public LaunchVehicleResponse countryRequest(MultiValueMap<String, Object> country);

instead of just Map class, because if I don't compiler says to me that Map and MultiValueMap aren't compatible. Anyway, that doesn't solve my problem :\

Please see my edit on main post to see server-side.


Thanks !

Comment: Log the request first, what it is sending now? Anyway, this snippet should work.

Comment: First pardon me for my beginnerness, I'm still learning right now ;)
I guess you want me to create and implement an interceptor. Sadly I can't make it work... I made my logging class as in here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24493615/rest-client-logging-for-androidannotations
In a new file, and add this to my @Rest annotation : interceptors = { LoggingInterceptor.class }, but I'm unable to log anything :(

Comment: You already have a server, you should be able to log requests there. Or you can just check it with Wireshark.

Comment: Ok, I was able to log requests incoming in server, that's good.
When I send my request from Advanced Rest Client, the server get this : country=USA (and it works). When I do it from my app (with , it gets that : {"country":["Europe"]} (I think "Europe shouldn't be in an array anyway). I guess I have some kind of an encoding / decoding problem somewhere...